# Thread safe engine and connection in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

This question has been asked many times but all of them end up relating with the Session and how one can manage it when using the ORM but I am not using the ORM and rely directly on connection.execute.

In our scenario we have many threads that need to be sending queries to a database. My question is what is the best way of handling this scenario with SQLAlchemy given that the engine and connection are not thread safe?

Should we have one central engine and each thread get one connection? Should we have one engine per thread? I am not sure what the best approach is and as soon as we start sending queries against AWS Redshift with more than one thread the process seems to hung.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: "Should we have one central engine and each thread get one connection?" Yes. The engine is thread-safe, given that the pool in use is, i.e. it will not serve the same connection to 2 threads. SQLite's in-memory DBs are an exception to the rule: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#using-a-memory-database-in-multiple-threads, due to how they work (they exist within the connection only).

Comment: So, it is completely fine to share an engine and allow it to internally supply connections to the different threads? Sounds perfect, thanks! I was reading about it in the docs but could not find anything specific.